# Get penultimate git tag on branch, matching a given glob

Tags: git

I have a git repo with commits on the master branch, each of which may have multiple tags:

```
HASH: TAGS
hash7: [v6.0.0, foo1, foo2, foo3]
hash6: []
hash5: []
hash4: [v5.0.0, bar1, bar2, bar3]
hash3: [v4.0.0, baz1, baz2, baz3]
hash2: []
hash1: [v3.0.0, foobar1, foobar2, foobar3]
```

I have a github action that is triggered by the creation of *version* tag (`v.*.*.*`). This action needs to be able to figure out the previous version tag. So, for example, if the action runs on `hash7` (`v6.0.0`), it should return `v5.0.0`. If it runs on `hash4` (`v5.0.0`), it should return `v4.0.0`, etc.

There are a number of stackoverflow questions that relate to this. I have tried various combinations of:

- `git describe --match 'v*' --tags`
- `git rev-list --tags='v*' --max-count=1 --skip=1`
- `git describe --tags --match "v*" --abbrev=0 git rev-list --tags="v*" --max-count=1 --skip=1`

The latter, for example, when run on `v6.0.0` gives the latest tag (`v6.0.0`) when run without the skip option, but gives `v4.0.0` when the skip option is set as 1.

I've done quite a bit of googling, but I can't find anything reliable.

To summarise, I'm after: *The nearest version tag (not including the one attached to the commit that is currently at the HEAD), on this branch*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just skip `HEAD`:

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --match="v*" --tags HEAD~
```